# Git restore unstaged file that was deleted after pull

Tags: git

I had unstaged file (e.g. index.html) in my repo and pulled a commit where this unstaged file was deleted. Is there any way I can restore this file?

Comment: I think you might be out of luck in this case.  One possibility would be if the file is somehow still open in your IDE, you can check for this.  For future reference, don't do things like pulling and checking out commits if there be any chance that your working directory has valuable work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restore deleted file not staged in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24911809/restore-deleted-file-not-staged-in-git)

Comment: Note that if you mean `git pull`, `git pull` should, like `git merge`, *refuse to run* if you have any modified files in your index or work-tree. Older versions of Git got this wrong, in various ways and of varying amounts of severity: `git merge` usually gets it right even in ancient Git, but `git pull` regularly wrecks everything in various corner cases. Never use `git pull`, especially if your Git predates 2.0.

Comment: Which version of git are you using?