# Recover a deleted local repository

Tags: git, command-line, delete-file

I had been working on a project for several hours and when trying to push it to GitHub somehow (from the command line) I ended deleting all the files contained in the folder of the project.

Now there is nothing in GitHub neither locally in my computer. Is there anything I can do to recover my files?

When I check git status all it says is your branch is up to date.

HELP

Comment: Does your work exist somewhere in a different branch?  Have you committed _any_ of the work prior to deleting everything?  Did you push _anything_ to GitHub previously?  If the answer to the above is all no, then there is nothing you can do.  Maybe check the recycle bin if you are running Windows.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24911809/restore-deleted-file-not-staged-in-git

Comment: Indeed, I was trying to do the first push...somehow I managed to mess up everything. Guess there's nothing left to do :(       . Thanks

Comment: Run `git log` to see if you have any previous commits of the work. If you do, try `git checkout HEAD~1` to checkout the previous commit, and increase the number to go further back. If you don't have any previous commits, you can try an "undelete" program however it might not be worth it for only a few hours' work.  Don't worry, it's always quicker doing something the second time around!  You might like to look at some sort of continuous backup mechanism, personally I use `git` for that.

Comment: Personally I would try `ntfsundelete` to recover a deleted file from windows,  using an Ubuntu live CD, if you already have or can get one using a different computer. https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13706/recover-deleted-files-on-an-ntfs-hard-drive-from-a-ubuntu-live-cd/

Comment: What editor/IDE did you use? Some of them maintain a local history.

Comment: hey guys! It seems that @SamWatkins had the right answer. I was using Git Bash in the command line and somehow I deleted the files but I didn't typed add . (what I understand is that it adds to the local repository the changes done since the last commmit or add .) so I could do reflog and get the files back to my folder. thank you all

Comment: I use IntelliJ and editor local history really saved my day. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html